# If code gives error do.. javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

When a piece of javascript code gives an error in the console. How can I do something like: If this piece of code gives back an error execute another piece of code?

This is what I have:

```
try {
    var operator = <?=$this->shopRequest[operator]?>;
} catch(errorObj) {
    var operator = sessionStorage.getItem('operator');
}
```

This is the error I get in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: Look into `try...catch`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: try catch does not work, because I use a piece of php code, but I don't know why, because I get a normal error in the console as you can see in the edited post

Comment: What is the output of `<?=$this->shopRequest[operator]?>`. I would imagine it doesn't include the required quotes

Comment: You can't fix syntax errors without simply fixing the syntax errors.

Comment: Don't use try/catch. This this not the kind of error, that should be catched, it's an error that should be fixed. `$this->shopRequest[operator]` apparantly isn't what you expect it to be, so have a look at it. If it is supposed to be a string, maybe it would be enough to add quotes: `var operator = "<?=$this->shopRequest[operator]?>";`

Comment: Try to view a page's source code by hitting CTRL+U

Comment: @RGraham the output is a number. But it will not always give output, that's why I got the error. The code works

Comment: Adding the quotes worked!! Thanks!!

Comment: @NiekNijland you have to detect the situation in **PHP** and prevent the syntactically-incorrect code from being generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var operator = "<?=$this->shopRequest[operator]?>";
alert(operator);
```

**Edit**

of better:

```
var operator = "<?=str_replace('"', '\"', $this->shopRequest[operator])?>";
```

just in case it will contain `"` symbols

Comment: Given that the OP said in the comments (which looking at your answer *I'm sure you've read*) the output is a number, this is invalid logic. You shouldn't output this as a string if it is a number

Comment: Yes that's true, but now I use the number as a string which is oke, since I cannot get into the php code since that is back-end stuff and another guy in the company handles that.

Comment: I you want rep, add your answer and I will accept is as corret, since you were first and probably this is a rip-off of yours

Comment: I know I can access it in the cms I'm working, but I cannot do more then request values.

Comment: @RGraham I hadn't read your comment by that time I started to write my answer. Sometimes I use this approach when I need to pass value from PHP to JavaScript directly, and i don't want to wait till the page is loaded. So if you write your own answer I will remove my own, if you wish

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
try
{
  // Run some code here
}
catch(err)
{
  // Handle errors here; You can make a call to the other piece of code from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your answer you should use

```
try {
   // your code
} catch(e) {
   console.err('Ops ' + e); 
   // execute here other code
}
```